# Get instance name via curl on ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to get the actual name of the ec2 instance, for example:

[image]

I've been able to grab some of the lower-level data by doing stuff like:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/1.0/meta-data/hostname
```

But is it possible to get the name (or tags) anywhere without using some sort of `aws`, `ec2`, or `boto` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags data is not available through instance metadata, you would need aws-cli for that.

As of today, this is what's available:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
```

Fun fact: this [feature request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=57062&start=50&tstart=0) was suggested almost a decade ago